# jQuery function cannot be called without an alert present

Tags: jquery, alert, keydown

I have some click functions on my website. When I click on them, I want to toggle the class of a specific . This is the code I have to do that:

```
$(".phenomenology_toggle_box").click(function() {
    pageClicked = '.phenomenology_toggle_box';
    escClicked = !escClicked;
    $('.phenomenology_close').toggleClass("phenomenology");
});

$(".judith_toggle_box").click(function() {
    pageClicked = '.judith_toggle_box';
    escClicked = !escClicked;
    $('.judith_close').toggleClass("judith");
});
```

I also want to be able to call the function of the most recently clicked item when I press the ESC key. This is the code I have for that:

```
$(document).keydown(function escape(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && escClicked == false){ // Esc
        $(pageClicked).trigger('click');
        pageClicked = 'null';
        escClicked = true;
    }
});
```

The Esc key fails to call the function, unless I have an alert in the function I want to call. Like this:

```
$(".judith_toggle_box").click(function() {
    pageClicked = '.judith_toggle_box';
    escClicked = !escClicked;
    $('.judith_close').toggleClass("judith");
    //**************
    alert("Judith has been called.");
    //**************
});
```

How do I get the ESC key to call the function without having to add the stupid alert?

Answer (score 0):

In your click functions add an event parameter

And try adding this to the first line of your function - event.preventDefault();

So for example

```
$(".judith_toggle_box").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    pageClicked = '.judith_toggle_box';
    escClicked = !escClicked;
    $('.judith_close').toggleClass("judith");
});
```

EDIT: Forgot to add the event as a function parameter, please check again

Comment: What is an event parameter? Is it in your code? Because the only change I see is the "event.preventDefault();"

p.s. just adding that did not work.

Comment: Can you put your code in fiddler or something similar? It will be easier if I can test

Comment: I have, the problem is it works fine in [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mWZHX/3/)